# Find the distance travelled by $P$ before it changes direction. (Mechanics)

Tags: classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

A particle $P$ starts at the point $O$ and travels in a straight line. At time $t$ seconds after leaving $O$ the velocity of $P$ is v $m/s$, where $v = 0.75t^2 − 0.0625t^3$. Find

(i) the positive value of $t$ for which the acceleration is zero, [3]

(ii) the distance traveled by $P$ before it changes its direction of motion. [5]

I solved (i) and the answer is $t=8$ seconds.

For (ii) I integrated $v = 0.75t^2 − 0.0625t^3$, but stuck after that. Please help.

Comment: i want a clear answer...anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You are right for (i), now for (ii), you want to know when P changes it direction of motion, i.e. when $v$ is negative. So you just got to solve :
$$v(t) < 0 \iff (t>0 \text{ and } \frac{v(t)}{t} < 0) \text{ or } (t<0 \text{ and } \frac{v(t)}{t} > 0) $$

This is factoring by a root of the $v$ polynomial. Here, clearly $0$ is a root so you can factor $v$ by $t-0=t$.

Clearly, $t < 0$ isn't relevant, so you just got to solve :
$$0.75t - 0.0625t^2 < 0$$ 
Which is a $2$nd degree.

More generally, when you got such a problem, try to factor your polynomial, until you can get every single root of it, and then just find the sign of it.